# PowerPoint 2013 Macro Runs Slow (redrawing issue?)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a macro that is supposed to make every shape on a page visible (I have other macros that make them invisible). Here is the code:

```
Dim Slide As Integer
Slide = SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition
If Slide = 1 Then
    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes
        shp.Visible = True
    Next shp
End if
```

This macro takes *forever* to run. I suspect this is because it is redrawing the screen every time a shape is made visible.

This is not necessary, in fact the slide isn't even shown on the screen when this macro is run (it runs on Slide 1 but makes the shapes on Slide 2 visible). Is there any way to make this run faster? Disable the screen refresh or something?

I tried Shyam's solution from http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?33671-Solved-PP2010-ScreenUpdating-False but it doesn't work. His only goes up to 2010 and I'm using 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as shown.  I changed it to this, which works pretty much instantly on a slide with 175 shapes:

```
' Put this at the top of every module; builds character, keeps you out of trouble
Option Explicit  

Sub ThisWorks()

' Always dim ALL variables
Dim Slide As Long   ' SlideIndex is a Long, not an Integer
Dim oSh As Shape

' Replaced your SSW with this:
Slide = SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition
If Slide = 1 Then
    For Each oSh In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes
        ' I was toggling them back and forth as a test
        ' oSh.Visible = Not oSh.Visible
        oSh.Visible = True
    Next
End If

' Delete this when it's no longer needed
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: The reason the code doesn't work is I forgot to include the line to set the SSW variable to SlideShowWindows(1).
I'm not at work now, I'll try your new code out tomorrow and let you know if it works. Thanks!